# how to use getter or setter with mongoose timestamps?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use a `getter` or `setter` for timestamps fields in the schema (mongoose schema) in order to change those dates formats when fetching them from the database.

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema(
     {
        name: String,
        dob: {
                type: Date,
                get: (date) => {
                  if (date) return date.toISOString().split("T") [0];
                },
          },
     },
     {
          timestamps: true,
     }
);
```

is there a clear solution for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of your model please? Did you try implementing a getter/setter?

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution works well.

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema(
     {
        name: String,
        dob: {
                type: Date,
                get: (date) => {
                  if (date) return date.toISOString().split("T") [0];
                },
        },

        createdAt: {
                type: Date,
                get: (date) => timeSince(date),
        }
        updatedAt: {
                type: Date,
                get: (date) => timeSince(date),
        },
     },
     {
       timestamps: true,
       toJSON: { getters: true, virtuals: true },
     }
);
```

where `timeSince` is a function i defined.
and i use the json version of the model when i fetch it.

Comment: check https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7496